# ¿Cómo podría saber la id del <div> en el que se encuentra un determinado elemento?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Agrego a la "dama" dentro de una id de una determinada caja (esto se realiza en una función a parte)

```
$("#" + ladyid + "").appendTo("#" + boxid + "");
```

pues lo que quiero saber en la otra funcion (la de abajo), es saber a que id (de las cajas) ha ido la dama

```
setInterval(function() {

                var lady1 = ;
                var lady2 = ;
                var lady3 = ;
                var lady4 = ;
                var lady5 = ;
                var lady6 = ;
                var lady7 = ;
                var lady8 = ;

            });
```

Lo que pretendo es que el programa sepa todo el rato en que div se encuentra cada elemento, y esta información añadirla a una variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto lo puedes hacer usando la propiedad `parent()` para saber cual es el div padre en el que se encuentra la dama y posteriormente usar `.attr('id')` para sacar el id del mismo. Te dejo un ejemplo para que lo veas más claro:

```js
var dama = $("#dama").appendTo("#primero");
alert(dama.parent().attr('id'));
```

```css
.contenedor{
  position: relative;
  border: 1px white solid;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#dama{
  position: absolute; 
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="primero" class ="contenedor"></div>
<div id="segundo" class ="contenedor"></div>
<div id="dama"></div>
```

En tu caso si estás en una función distinta deberías de usar `$("#dama").parent().attr('id');`

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: @Javi De nada! Al editar tu pregunta entendí lo que querías.